# Putting the social dialogs (facebook, ln, g+, tweeter) in a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, facebook, dialog, load

I am trying to have my social share buttons (facebook,linkedin, tweeter, google+) creating their dialog in jquery dialog popup
Here is my code (come from stackoverflow)

```
<div id="example"></div>
<div id="showdialog">facebook</div>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dialogOpts = {
    title: "Share on facebook",
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    open: function() {
         $("#example").load("http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://mysite.com");}
    };
 $("#example").dialog(dialogOpts);
 $('#showdialog').click(function (){
        $("#example").dialog("open");
        return false;
 });
});
```

But I get this error

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://mysite.com. Origin http://droit-inc.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Is it a security issue? Is it a way to have all these dialogs a little more the same...
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

From the [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

---

## see [**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

---

Alternatives that you can consider are:

[**YQL**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/)

[**JSONP**](http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/)